# ANOVA: testing assumption of normality for many groups with few samples per group

Tags: anova, normal-distribution, small-sample

Assume the following situation:

we have a large number (e.g. 20) with small group sized (e.g. n = 3). I noticed that if I generate values from the uniform distribution, the residuals will look approximately normal even though the error distribution is uniform. The following R code demonstrates this behaviour:

```
n.group = 200
n.per.group = 3

x <- runif(n.group * n.per.group)
gr <- as.factor(rep(1:n.group, each = n.per.group))
means <- tapply(x, gr, mean)
x.res <- x - means[gr]
hist(x.res)
```

If I look at the residual of a sample in a group of three, the reason for the behaviour is clear:

$
r_1 = x_1 - \text{mean}(x1, x2, x3) = x1 - \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}=\frac{2}{3}x_1 - x_2 - x_3.
$

[image]

Since $r_1$ is a sum of random variables with a not roughly different standard deviation its distribution is quite a bit closer to the normal distribution than the individual terms.

Now assume I have the same situation with real data instead of simulated data. I want to assess whether the ANOVA assumptions regarding normality holds. Most recommended procedures recommend visual inspection of the residuals (e.g. QQ-Plot) or a normality test on the residuals. As my example above this is not really optimal for small group sizes.

Is there an better alternative when I have many groups of small sizes?

Comment: For several reasons it appears this is a non-problem.  First, your residuals will appear uniform: look at a histogram for a huge number of groups to see this.  Second, the normality of the residuals is of little importance for most analyses; what matters is the approximate normality of sampling distributions.  What special aspect of your application, then, causes you to suppose there is any real problem?

Comment: a) my residuals will not appear uniform. I have tested this for a number of groups (not samples per group) from 20 to 20000. I have attached an example to the question; it appears like a something between uniform and normal, with a distinct trend to normal.
b) I know that it is about the approximate normality of the sampling distribution. This is the entire point of the question as the residuals will look normal, but the sampling distribution is not. So I cannot use the residuals to test the properties of the sampling distribution.

Comment: That is correct.  But are you really interested in the distribution of the errors or are you interested in performing ANOVA?  (I'm not trying to imply the question should be ignored--it's a fascinating issue you have raised--but I'm only wondering whether you really need an answer in order to proceed with your data analysis.)

Comment: @whuber I don't need the answer for a specific analysis, it's more of a general matter. I think it's relevant since the combination of many groups and few samples per group comes up more often than one might wish. In the specific case of 3 samples per group you neither have enough samples to use most non-parametric statistics or to be robust against violations of normality. For example, the above example still works when I add x <- x^2, introducing a distinct skew. In this case, it seems difficult to impossible to test the requirements of the ANOVA.

Comment: But you can use the same simulations to investigate the robustness of the ANOVA in your case!

Comment: One slightly tangential but relevant comment: In general, using a test for normality (or another model assumption) before doing a hypothesis test presents (at least) three problems: 1) If you do it, you need to account for multiple testing; 2) Rejecting the alternate hypothesis e.g., "not normal" doesn't mean that you can conclude normality; 3) Tests for model assumptions have their own model assumptions, so where do you stop?

Comment: This is a common observation with regression models -- that the residuals are closer to normally distributed than the errors. Of course since errors are unobserved we can usually only demonstrate it via simulation. A common choice is to take exponential errors (mean-corrected) and see that the residuals are less skew than the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Working on this answer, not completely done. I have some insight on this but it takes a while to explain. For this, let us consider that standard deviation is biased for small numbers. The reason for this is that if we take any two numbers $a<b$, we arbitrarily assign the sample mean to be $\frac{a+b}2{}$, where the population mean, $\sigma$, could very well be anywhere on the interval between $(a,b)$ or it could be that $\sigma<a$ or $\sigma>b$. This means that on the average $\text{SD}<\sigma$. Thus,  It is only when $n>100$ that [this bias becomes small](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation). For a long series of SD's for small numbers of samples each, the SD calculation becomes more precise, and more obviously inaccurate.

Now, rather than throw our hands up in frustration, we can apply the small number correction for our SD's under normal conditions. (Ha! There is a solution to our misery.)

$\frac{SD(n)}{\mu(n)}\,=\,\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}\,\,\,\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}
 \, = \, 1 - \frac{1}{4n} - \frac{7}{32n^2} - \frac{19}{128n^3} + O(n^{-4})$ see [$E[\mu]$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation)

For $n=3$, this is $\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\approx0.8862269255$. Which means that we have to divide our SD by that much to estimate $\sigma$.

Now in the case you present you have several other things going on as well. As it happens, the best measure of location of a uniform distribution is not the mean. Although both the sample mean and the sample median are unbiased estimators of the midpoint, neither is as efficient as the sample mid-range, i.e., the arithmetic mean of the sample maximum and the sample minimum, which is the minimum-variance unbiased estimator [UMVU estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-variance_unbiased_estimator) of the midpoint (and also the maximum likelihood estimate).

Now to the meat of the matter. If you use the average of the extreme values, the variance of the measure of location will be smaller, provided that your data is truly uniform distributed. It may be normally distributed because a single extreme value tail might well be normal. With only 3-samples, however, the standard deviation will need correction.